# What is a tire bubble?

Tags: tires

I was looking at some reviews on tires and a couple of places people were using this term of a "tire bubble". Sounds like an imperfection or weak spot on the tire wall where some sort of bulge is sticking out like a hernia for a tire or something. What exactly is a `tire bubble` and what causes it and how dangerous is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tire bubble is exactly as you think it is: a defect in the tire which causes air to *bubble up* between the layers of rubber. This is a weak spot in the tire and can be very dangerous. If the tire were to pop at the weak spot at the most inopportune time, the resulting blowout could cause an accident. While an accident is not a given, it is one possibility which is a very real possibility.

Here is an image of a "minor" tire bubble:

[image]

Taken to the extreme, it could look something like this:

[image]

Comment: wow I was going to say that was a minor one, looked huge to me, that is until I saw the extreme one.